# How do I correct for type I error in a mediation when using Hayes' PROCESS in SPSS?

Tags: p-value, bootstrap, mediation, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have performed three mediation analyses using PROCESS in SPSS, each with a different outcome/dependent variable. To prevent a type I error, I would like to perform a correction for this, but seeing as PROCESS doesn't give a p-value, I have no clue how to do this. Is there a way to use the bootstrapping interval to correct for the type I error? Or do I have to do it differently?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy solution if you want to apply a correction is to change the wideness of the confidence interval. You can take .05/3 which is .01666, so 1-.0166 = 98 to 99% CI which should be good enough to correct for type I error.

Because you have performed three different models, so you tested, in fact, three different hypotheses, you could also not apply a correction.

Finally, if the three models are related, and depending on your data, you could try to use structural equation modelling.